# Problem during Deploy ShinyWebApp to rstudio-connect

Tags: r, linux, deployment, connection

I have a problem with deployment of the ShinyWebApp to RStudio Connect.
The static content, like Rmd or pdf are fine, but during deployment of shinyWebApp (I used the template ShinyWebApp without any special libraries) I get after long time this error message:

```
GET /__api__/tasks/f5IgRmpgGHqgw6dW?first_status=20 470ms
[Connect] 2020/11/04 08:36:23.599622953 Error in hash(descFile): No DESCRIPTION file at path '/opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/app/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.0.3/BH/DESCRIPTION'!
[Connect] 2020/11/04 08:36:23.599645555 
[Connect] 2020/11/04 08:36:23.599678757 Unable to fully restore the R packages associated with this deployment.
[Connect] 2020/11/04 08:36:23.599680357 Please review the preceding messages to determine which package
[Connect] 2020/11/04 08:36:23.599690758 encountered installation difficulty and the cause of the failure.
[Connect] 2020/11/04 08:36:23.604026624 Warning message:
[Connect] 2020/11/04 08:36:23.604160836 In packrat::restore(overwrite.dirty = TRUE, prompt = FALSE, restart = FALSE) :
[Connect] 2020/11/04 08:36:23.604167036   The most recent snapshot was generated using R version 4.0.2
GET /__api__/tasks/f5IgRmpgGHqgw6dW?first_status=28 189ms
[Connect] Build error: exit status 1
GET /__api__/applications/4/config 220ms
----- Deployment log finished at  2020-11-04 09:36:25  -----
Warning message:
Error detecting locale: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'raw'
 (Using default: en_US)
```

It looks like the issue with BH package, but this package is already there and installed properly:

```sh
root@RSCONNECT_MACHINE:/ # ls -la /opt/R/3.6.2/lib/R/library/BH/
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Nov  3 11:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Nov  3 11:56 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1616 Nov  3 11:56 DESCRIPTION
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  3 11:56 help
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  3 11:56 html
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov  3 11:56 include
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   47 Nov  3 11:56 INDEX
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  3 11:56 Meta
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   31 Nov  3 11:56 NAMESPACE
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7535 Nov  3 11:56 NEWS.Rd
```

**RStudio Desktop**

- Version 1.3.1056
- "Water Lily" (5a4dee98, 2020-07-07) for Windows
- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36
  R version on local computer R-4.0.2

**RStudio Connect v1.8.4.2-2**

- Build "v1.8.4.2"
- Available R Versions:

  - 4.0.3
  - 3.6.3
  - 3.6.2
- Available Python Version:

  - 3.6.5

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you use Rstudio Connect, can I assume that you are a client of theirs? If so, you can get in touch with their support about this.

Comment: Yes, but they have some limitation of support to other packages (R package issues fall outside of their support) so I am looking at other directions.

Comment: Solved by added this (and other packages) into rstudio-connect.gcfg `[Packages]
External = BH   ExternalsCheckIsFatal = false`